# How to dynamically render a <div> content on click of a button without reloading the whole content?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax

Details:

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div ng-app="sampleAngular">
            <div id="panel-1" ng-controller="Controller1">
              <!-- some html code here that displays a table of information-->
            </div>
            <p><button type="button" onclick="onSubmit();" name="subscribe">Subscribe to Panel-2 Info</button> </p>
            <div id="panel-2" ng-controller="Controller2">
              <!-- some html code here that displays another table of information-->
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Question**:
The content in div id "panel-2" should be displayed only when the user clicks "Subscribe to Panel-2 Info" button. The button should update a record in DB, and then render the content in div id "panel-2" without refreshing the whole page. How to implement this requirement - any ajax logic in onSubmit() function?

**Note**: I should not render the whole page and then set *visibility: false* around "panel-2" as I shouldn't call the controller "*ng-controller="Controller2*" until the user subscribes (clicks the button).

Answer (score 1):

In your `onSubmit()` function, make your Ajax call which should return the results that you want in HTML, or as data which you then HTML format it in JavaScript and display it using the `innerHTML` property. Here is an example (click the button to see how it works):

```js
function onSubmit() {
  //make your Ajax call here

  //if the Ajax was successful, display the result
  document.getElementById("panel-2").innerHTML = "some html code here that displays another table of information (this is the result of the Ajax call)";
  //if the Ajax resulted in error, display an error message
  //document.getElementById("panel-2").innerHTML = "an error occurred";
}
```

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div ng-app="sampleAngular">
    <div id="panel-1" ng-controller="Controller1">
      some html code here that displays a table of information
    </div>
    <p><button type="button" onclick="onSubmit();" name="subscribe">Subscribe to Panel-2 Info</button> </p>
    <div id="panel-2" ng-controller="Controller2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate your response Racil. The html content that goes into innerHTML is huge, like 30 lines of html code. Can you think of a way to package that html and call it in innerHTML ?

Comment: 30 lines is not huge. I've done more than that numerous times. What do you mean packaging? Typically, your server should be returning the HTML and just assign the retuned Ajax result to `innerHTML`, no packaging is required as the server automatically gzips it. Alternatively, if your server is returning pure data and then your JavaScript takes the retuned Ajax result and format it in HTML, then you're assigning it to a variable and also no packaging here.